# deeppavlov - tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Requested more than 0 entries, but params is empty

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run deepPavlov on a remote server.
After successfully installing the [deepPavlov module](http://docs.deeppavlov.ai/en/master/intro/installation.html) and downloading the associated models, I ran the demo script:

```
from deeppavlov import configs, build_model
ner_model = build_model(configs.ner.ner_ontonotes_bert, download=False)
ner_model(['Bob Ross lived in Florida'])
```

But I got the following error, which appends on line 3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1365, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/test/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _run_fn
    target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/home/test/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1443, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Requested more than 0 entries, but params is empty.  Params shape: [1,7,0]
     [[{{node ner_1/GatherNd}}]]
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you first executed `install` to install all requirements.

`python -m deeppavlov install ner_ontonotes_bert`

Then set `download` to `True`

Comment: it is not working either, I still get the same error...

Comment: @GLNB This error message is similar to what was mentioned on the [forum](https://forum.deeppavlov.ai/t/can-anyone-help-me-find-what-error-is-this/174). Please make sure that `ner_ontonotes_bert` has original settings, and the paths are set correctly.